# how to deal with categorical data when training data has not got all expected categories?

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data

My data has a feature called level, and the data may have levels(-1,0,1,2,3) but my data now has only 2 levels 0 and -1. I'm using python for binary classification. How to do one-hot-encoding with all levels? What is the right approach to deal with this problem? Can I include all levels as I may expect them in test data? Or should I use only 2 levels ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite it in this block.

Levels in train data:

```
(-1, 0)
```

Levels in test data:

```
(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
```

I think that the best way will be:

- create 2 columns for train data (1st column will have 1 where value == -1 and 0 otherwise; 2nd column will have 1 where value == 0 and 0 otherwise)
- group (1, 2, 3) in test data
- do the same encoding as in the first bullet but for group you will have 0 in the first column and 0 in the second column

So you will have 2 levels in general (for value == -1 and value == 0) and 3rd level where all values in one-hot-encoded vector will be equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the idea sounds interesting but Im not sure if that solves my problem because that treats 1,2,3 categories as single category to my understanding!

Comment: Sure. But if you don't have categories 1, 2, 3 in train set how do you plan to train the model?

Answer (score 0):

If **X=[-1,0,1,2,3]**, for `onehot` you can try:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one_hot_enc=OneHotEncoder()
X_onehot=one_hot_enc.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1)) #reshape to convert 1-d array to 2-d array
print(X_onehot.toarray())
```

Since you have negative values like **-1** in your class, trying `one_hot` will throw

```
ValueError: X needs to contain only non-negative integers.
```

for this you can first try Label-encoding first:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc=LabelEncoder()
x_new=enc.fit_transform(X)
print(x_new.classes_)
```

feed **x_new** in place of **X** to `OneHotEncoder`

Comment: Thanks for the code but my concern was something different. I wanted to do include levels that were not present in my train data which I expect to be present in test data